# How to write logs in text file but do not overwrite the file

Tags: java, logging

How to write logs in text file  but do not overwrite the file?

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");  
FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("C:/temp/test/MyLogFile.log");  
logger.addHandler(fh);
...
logger.info("log sample");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to append text to an existing file in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this :

```
FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("C:/temp/test/MyLogFile.log");
```

to this

```
FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("C:/temp/test/MyLogFile.log", true);
```

If you read the documentation you will see that the second argument specifies the optional *append* argument. When true you will write at the end of the (existing) file, without overwriting it.

See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html#FileHandler(java.lang.String,%20boolean))